# How to stop pushing values in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running the following:

```
function wikiText() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(spacetime)), null, 4));
  var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&disablelimitreport=true&format=json&prop=text|langlinks&noimages=true&mobileformat=true&page="+ curTitle + "&callback=?";
  $.getJSON(url,function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        spacetime[0].Title.push(curTitle);
        for(var i = 0; i < dateText.length; i++) {
          d += dateText[i] + ' ';
        }
        var words = d.split(" ");
        var array = words;
        var newArray = array.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
        for (const word of newArray) {
          if (months.has(word)) {
              spacetime[0].Time.months.push(word);
          } else if (+word < 32) {
              spacetime[0].Time.days.push(+word);
          } else if (+word < 2200) {
              spacetime[0].Time.years.push(+word);
          } else if (/\w+/.test(word)) {
              spacetime[0].Time.suffixes.push(word);
          }
        }
        let pattern = new RegExp('^\/wiki\/');
        doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').each(function(index, el) { 
          result = $(this).attr('href').replace(pattern, '');
          countryPage();  
        });
      };
    });
  });
}
```

And that in reality is a function which is called by another function `function newQuery() {.. wikiText();`
That first bit of code then runs another function `function countryPage() {` but this one isn't pushing `spacetime[0].Time...`

However I get duplicated values like:

```
"days": [
                27,
                28,
                27,
                28,
                19,
                22,
                27,
                28,
                19,
                22,
                27,
                28,
                19,
                22,
```

I don't understand why it is duplicating the values as if it was saving them and re-pushing them each time the function is called.

I do have a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/881/) just be patient for a bit as it is doing a lot of parsings.(see console.log).

I need:

```
"days": [
                27,
                28,
                19,
                22,
```

Comment: your data could be having duplicate dates.

Comment: @Dij it's not, if i do `console.log(newArray);` the data is fine :(

Comment: you are getting so many articles in reponse data, there are surely repeating dates.

Comment: @Dij they will be surely repeating dates, yet not in this case and at this point of the loop, because I do a lot of conditionals and i can console.log the title and also i check the full string and no, they are not repeating dates but a bug in the loop because these are the exact same dates of the same article for sure